# How do I check if JDBC batching is really working?

Tags: hibernate

I read this article about jdbc batching and it suggests that I turn on `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true`
 to check if batching really worked.

So when I tried it and did a bunch of insert statements, the logs showed me this.

```
27933133 nanoseconds spent executing 2 JDBC batches;
```

So it really did work. But I wondered what the  sql statements look like, so I tried to turn on the SQL logging `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG`. I tried to save 10 items, and I expected that with a batch size of 5, I would see 2 insert SQL statements. However, when I looked through the logs, I saw 10 insert SQL statements... Why is that? Here is the article btw: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-batch-insert-update

Did I misunderstand the article? If jdbc did the batching, why am I seeing 10 SQL statements instead of 2?

Here's my config:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=5
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.batch_versioned_data=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

Comment: Good question, I'm also interested :) FYI, just the number of executed batches can be seen in logs if following loglevel is enalbed: `<logger name="org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch" level="DEBUG"/>`

Comment: It will print something like this:  ```o.h.e.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch  : Executing batch size: 1```

Comment: Hmm, org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch logs nothing for me...